# Back Button on exit creating a Force Close Error

Tags: java, android, exit, ondestroy

I am trying to avoid using onDestroy and want to keep this as simple as possible, but when I exit the program, I get a Force Close error.  Not sure why.  Here is the code for the main part of the application.  Any suggestions?

**Main Application Code**

```
   public class Quotes extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

   ProgressDialog dialog;
   private WebView webview;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);

          WebView adsview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ads);
          adsview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
          adsview.loadUrl("http://www.dgdevelco.com/quotes/androidad.html");

          SharedPreferences SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

          String q = SP.getString("appViewType","http://www.dgdevelco.com/quotes/quotesandroidtxt.html");
          String c = SP.getString("appRefreshRate","20");

          webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
          webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
          webview.setWebViewClient(new QuotesWebView(this));
          webview.loadUrl(q);

          ScheduledExecutorService timer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
          timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

 @Override
 public void run() {
          webview.reload();
          }

 }, 10, Long.parseLong(c),TimeUnit.SECONDS);

 findViewById(R.id.refresh).setOnClickListener(this);


 }

 @Override
 public void onPause(){
          super.onPause();
 }

 @Override
 public void onResume(){
          super.onResume();
 }


 public void onClick(View v){
          switch(v.getId()){
          case R.id.refresh:
               webview.reload();
               break;
          }
 }


 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
          inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

          MenuItem about = menu.getItem(0);
          about.setIntent(new Intent(this, About.class));

          MenuItem preferences = menu.getItem(1);
          preferences.setIntent(new Intent(this, Preferences.class));

          return true;

 }

 }
```

**LogCat**

```
 07-04 13:34:55.011: INFO/DevicePushListener(1415): Connection State Changed: NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
 07-04 13:34:55.011: WARN/WindowManager(1314): Attempted to add application window with unknown token HistoryRecord{40c40f50 com.dge.quotes/.Quotes}.  Aborting.
 07-04 13:34:55.034: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(24137): Shutting down VM
 07-04 13:34:55.034: WARN/dalvikvm(24137): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
 07-04 13:34:55.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24137): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-04 13:34:55.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24137): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@40517fb0 is not valid; is your activity running?
 07-04 13:34:55.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24137):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:527)
 07-04 13:34:55.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24137):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
 07-04 13:34:55.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24137):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
 07-04 13:34:55.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24137):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
 07-04 13:34:55.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24137):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
 07-04 13:34:55.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24137):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107)
 07-04 13:34:55.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24137):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:90)
 07-04 13:34:55.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24137):     at com.dge.quotes.QuotesWebView.onPageStarted(QuotesWebView.java:22)
 07-04 13:34:55.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24137):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:271)
 07-04 13:34:55.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24137):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 07-04 13:34:55.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24137):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 07-04 13:34:55.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24137):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
 07-04 13:34:55.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24137):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-04 13:34:55.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24137):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 07-04 13:34:55.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24137):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 07-04 13:34:55.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24137):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 07-04 13:34:55.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24137):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 07-04 13:34:55.089: WARN/ActivityManager(1314):   Force finishing activity com.dge.quotes/.Quotes
```

Comment: Could you please post the exception and stacktrace that appear in Logcat?

Comment: Added it to the Question.  Thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 2):

Its written in your stacktrace

> Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@40517fb0 is not valid; is your activity running

You start a thread that does a reload

You then press back

Your activity finished

The thread returns and tries to draw on your activity

Oops its already finished

Comment: @Chris you need to call timer.shutdownNow() in your onPause(); API: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow()

Comment: Wouldn't that shut down the timer in the application?

Comment: Your timer is coupled with your application, and the application is 'shutdown' when you press back so you can't have the timer running trying to call a non existent app

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the example code provided on the `ScheduledExecutorService` documentation page:

```
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;
 class BeeperControl {
   private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
     Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

   public void beepForAnHour() {
     final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
       public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); 
     };
     final ScheduledFuture beeperHandle =
       scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
     scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
       public void run() { beeperHandle.cancel(true); }
     }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
   }
 }}
```

(http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

As others have said, the problem is that the `ScheduledExecutorService` keeps running and reloading the page even after the user closes that activity. To fix this, you can stop the `ScheduledExecutorService` in `onPause`.

Calling `scheduleAtFixedFate()` returns a `ScheduledFuture` object. Store this object and then call `cancel(true)` on it in your `onPause()` method.

Comment: Hmmm...  That doesn't seem to quite fit, but am just a beginner so what do I know.  :)  Maybe something that will just shut it down when exiting.

Comment: That actually exactly what I was suggesting. Adding a call to `timer.cancel(true)` in `onPause()` will shut down the ScheduledExecutorTask when the Activity exits. You will also need to restart it on `onResume()`.

Comment: I keep getting errors when I try that.  Maybe I am writing the code wrong?  @Override
   public void onPause(){
    timer.cancel(true);
    super.onPause();
   }
   ???

Answer (score 0):

Your activity is already stopped when it reaches that line of code. Refer to the exchange in this "bug" report in the Android forum: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3953